# Confused as to why my algorithm is running slower than it should be

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, primes

Purely for fun, I decided to write a simple algorithm that finds all the prime numbers between 2 and x, where x is whatever you want it to be.  I am using a `clock_t` to time how long it takes the algorithm to finish for varying x values. (I go x=0, then 25000, then 50000, then 75000, ..., up to 1,000,000).  For example, when x = 25000, I go into a for loop with `i` going from 2 to 25000, and for each value of `i`, I check to see if it's prime by dividing it with every number between two and itself, looking for a remainder of 0.

Here is the algorithm:

```
vector<int> calcPrimesWithoutPrechecking(int upperLimit)
{
    vector<int> res;

    for(int i = 2; i <= upperLimit; i++)
    {
        int currentNum = i;
        bool foundDivisible = false;
        for(int j = 2; j < currentNum; j++)
        {
            if(currentNum % j == 0)
            {
                foundDivisible = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!foundDivisible)
        {
            res.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

I figured I could make this faster by checking the last digit of the number we're currently testing.  If that digit is a 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, or 8, then I don't have to even check if it's prime because I know it's not (of course 2, 3, and 5 are, so those are handled in the beginning).  I'm calling this *prechecking*.  Here is the algorithm with prechecking:

```
vector<int> calcPrimesWithPrechecking(int upperLimit)
{
    vector<int> res;
    res.push_back(2);res.push_back(3);res.push_back(5);    
    for(int i = 6; i <= upperLimit; i++)
    {
        bool foundDivisible = false;    
        int lastDig = i%10;
        if(lastDig == 0
            || lastDig == 2
            || lastDig == 4
            || lastDig == 6
            || lastDig == 8
            || lastDig == 5)
        {
            foundDivisible = true;
        }    

        int currentNum = i;
        for(int j = 2; j < currentNum && !foundDivisible; j++)
        {
            if(currentNum % j == 0)
            {
                foundDivisible = true;
                break;
            }
        }    

        if(!foundDivisible)
        {
            res.push_back(i);
        }
    }    
    return res;
}
```

I output the results to the console, as well as write them to a text file.  I then copy the times over to excel, and plot them.  However, for some reason the algorithm with prechecking is slower.  I was almost sure it would be faster.  When I run the program, I purposefully close every program on my computer and I run it in release mode.  I have tested each algorithm in debug and they are indeed both working as intended.

[Here is my data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyr4l.png)

The x axis is the the number of primes we're checking (eg 25000 means we're looking for all primes between 2 and 25000), and the y axis is the time in seconds to get all the primes.

Can someone explain why the second algorithm, which should theoretically take out many of the computations, is in fact slower?

Comment: It would be much easier, and would help efficiency slightly, to only iterate over the odd numbers. Change the outer loop to `for(int i = 7; i <= upperLimit; i += 2)`.

Comment: Optimal trial division is `~ n^1.35..1.45` and sieve of Eratosthenes `~ n~1.05..1.1`, in `n` primes produced. Your algorithm is `~ n^2 ~ x^2/(log x)^2` and indeed your data at 1mln vs 400K [**empirically**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth)  is `~ x^1.92`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it *doesn't* take out many of the computations. If a number is even, that will be discovered immediately upon checking whether it is divisible by 2 (which is the first number you check in your loop). That's a lot faster than what you're doing here:

```
int lastDig = i%10;
if(lastDig == 0
    || lastDig == 2
    || lastDig == 4
    || lastDig == 6
    || lastDig == 8
    || lastDig == 5)
```

Comment: Also, if that succeeds it doesn't skip the other for loop anyway.

Comment: @LachlanEaston: It does. Check the loop condition of the inner loop for the second version.

Comment: Wow.  This makes so much sense.  I can't believe this did not occur to me!

Answer (score 5):

The reason the implementation with pre-checking is a little slower is that it needs to do more work to eliminate many of the numbers that would be eliminated after the first step of the inner loop anyway.

Consider number `8` as an example: pre-checking needs to find a division remainder and perform five comparisons before eliminating it, while the program with no pre-checking eliminates `8` too, but with a single division by two and a comparison to zero.

The only number for which you may see a little win is `5`, but these are not nearly as common as even numbers, on which your program loses CPU cycles.

A better way to speed this one up is to avoid even numbers altogether: recall that [all prime numbers after `3` are either of the form `6*k+1` or `6*k-1`](http://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html). Now you can iterate nearly three times as fast!

Another thing is that you do not need to check divisors past the square root of the candidate prime (can you prove why this is so?) This change alone will give you a huge improvement.

Finally, a very useful trick is to store all the primes that you have discovered so far, and use them for your trial divisors. This will greatly improve the speed of your inner loop.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but it seems to be thinking some numbers are primes that are not really primes.  I'm for each value of i checking q = i/6 and r = i%6, and if r is 0, 2, 3, or 4, I know it's not prime, otherwise (if it's 1 or 5) it is prime.  It's getting mostly primes, but a few non primes are slipping in (25, 35, 55, 77, ...)

Comment: The loop should go like this: `for (int i = 1 ; 6*i < upperLimit ; i++) {int cand1 = 6*i-1; int cand2 = 6*i+1; ... }` Then test the two candidates using the inner `for` loop.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite following... How am I supposed to test the candidates?  What you are saying are "candidates" I thought were the results.  I'm not sure what I should be testing on the candidates.  The link you posted made the 6(q+1)-1 and 6q+1 steps seem like the last part of the test, not the first.

Comment: @xcdemon05 In your code `i` is the candidate prime. You test one candidate prime per iteration of the outer loop. In my loop, `6*i-1` and `6*i+1` are candidate primes. You need to test both of them for being prime, and add the ones that pass the test to the list of primes.

Comment: Hmm...I'm doing something wrong.  This is going much slower than either of my two previous versions.  Can you spot what I'm doing?  I'm sure it's something really stupid...  http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3f72

Comment: @xcdemon05 try `for(int j = 0; ; j++)
{ int p=res[j]; if( p > c1/p ) { res.push_back(c1); break; } if( c1 % p == 0 )
{
break;
}
}`.

Comment: @xcdemon05 One thing you should change there is to start `j` from `5`, not from `2`. `6*i+1` and `6*i-1` numbers are guaranteed not to be divisible by `2` or `3`, so the four checks per loop only speed things down.